# How do I change the check icon color in flutter filterChip

Tags: flutter

I need a way to change the check (✔) color to white. How do I achieve that[image: scrennshot of the current result]

Comment: Please share the code you are using for your current situation. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: show your code please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Black or white checkmark

You can change the color to either black or white based on a light or dark theme. You can change the theme globally or [wrap the specific widget within a Theme widget](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/themes#themes-for-part-of-an-application).

```dart
Theme(
  data: ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.dark
  ), // or shorthand => ThemeData.dark()
  child: FilterChip(
    label: Text('My chip'),
    onSelected: (value) {
      // ...
    },
  ),
);
```

### Other colors

There is currently no way to change the color of the checkmark in the `FilterChip` provided by the Material package to an arbitrary color. The way the checkmark is drawn can be found in [the source code for the `Chip` classes here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/fecf99ff1eee95c03c062169a9906a4bfde21375/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/chip.dart#L2477).

For future reference, this is the part of code that draws the checkmark:

```dart
void _paintCheck(Canvas canvas, Offset origin, double size) {
    Color paintColor;
    switch (theme.brightness) {
      case Brightness.light:
        paintColor = theme.showAvatar ? Colors.white : Colors.black.withAlpha(_kCheckmarkAlpha);
        break;
      case Brightness.dark:
        paintColor = theme.showAvatar ? Colors.black : Colors.white.withAlpha(_kCheckmarkAlpha);
        break;
    }
    ...
```

So it is only able to show either as black or white right now. If you want it colored, you'll have to resort to a custom widget.

You could also chime in on [the already opened issue on Flutters Github project](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29626).

Answer (score 4):

You can change the color of the checkmark by using checkMarkColor property

```
FilterChip(
        label: Text('Pizza'),
        shape: StadiumBorder(side: BorderSide()),
        checkmarkColor: Colors.red,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply wrap your `FilterChip` in a `Theme` widget, and set the desired `ThemeData` without changing your general app style.

```
Theme(
  data: ThemeData.dark(), // White color. Select light for black.
  child: FilterChip(
    label: Text('Test'),
    selected: _selected,
    onSelected: (val) {
      setState(() => _selected = val);
    },
    backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
    selectedColor: Colors.pink,
    labelStyle: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.white,
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 2):

You can work around this by using an Avatar and customising this to represent the tick mark, e.g.

```
FilterChip(
   label: Text(
      "label text",
         style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
      ),
      avatar: isSelected ? Icon(Icons.check, color: contrastColor(Colors.red)) : null,
      // selected: isSelected,
   },
)
```

The function `contrastColor` just looks at the supplied colour and chooses white or black depending upon its luminescence.

The animation effects when toggling ruin this slightly, so you may want to keep an 'empty' avatar rather than null if it looks bad.

Wrapping the `FilterChip` with a `Theme` sort of works but, for me at least, it rendered the background colours incorrectly (too dark) when flipping between light and dark themes.